# Universal image loader & lazy loading

Tags: android

I am working on android application in which i am fetching images from server link and displaying the same images in grid view. I have searched on Internet and i have found that there are two approaches mainly used for the same task : 1] Universal image loader & 2] Lazy loading. So can you please suggest me which is the better approach for professional level coding Or Is there any other approaches better than above mentioned two approaches? Kindly help.

Comment: Well you can actually combine those two approaches. Even universal image loader uses lazy loading approach.They are not separate.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of lazy loading..in this approach xml data is parsed and displayed image from parsed object using lazy loading  [Click here](http://d-codepages.com/index.php/android/android-advanced/24-xml-parsing-using-xmlpullparser-loading-images-using-lazy-loading)